# Group Rows by Multiple Columns using R then Statistical Analysis

Tags: r, statistics

Each row in the dataset has an id number, and each row lists a single product with the net price. Some deals have multiple items sold, hence the multiple rows with the same id number. How do I create groups of the rows so that they are grouped by product combination?

For example, IDs 1 and 4 show be seen as the same since they have the exact same products in the deals.

The end goal is to be able to create matching groups, then do a statistical analysis on these groups.[image: This is an example of the dataset]

Goal output:
[image]

I tried:
data_wide <- spread(dt, Product, Price)

Output:
'var' must evaluate to a single number or a column name, not a character vector

```
structure(list(`ID Number` = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4), Product = c("A", 
"B", "D", "A", "A", "B", "A", "B", "D"), Price = c(8, 7, 11, 
4, 5, 9, 10, 3, 5)), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

[image: Error message with backtrace]

Comment: What is the output you hope for?

Comment: The output I am looking for is to go from long to wide format and then group by same unique product mixes. For example, one group (let's say called, "ABD") will have all transactions that have only products A, B, and D, which in this case will include the rows of ID 1 and 4.

Comment: Could you edit that into your question... and maybe show what it would look like for your example data? I think I'm starting to get the idea, but it's not perfectly clear yet. You'll also make it much easier to help if you share sample data that is copy/pasteable---`dput` is a great function for that, putting `dput(your_data[1:9, ])` in your question would be perfect. Pictures of data are very difficult to work with.

Comment: Edited the post to reflect the desired output

Comment: Your code, `spread(dt, Product, Price)`, looks good. If it didn't work, there must be an issue that we can't really diagnose from a picture. Can you edit into your question the output from `dput(dt)` or `dput(dt[1:9, ])` so that we can test on something that looks like your actual data?

Comment: Ok added the dput() results to the question

Comment: When I create the data from your dput `dt = structure(list...` and run `tidyr::spread(dt, Product, Price)`, I get the result you want. Can you verify again that isn't working?

Comment: I tried it your way, too, just to see and I get the same error message. I included it in the question

Comment: Use `spread(dt, Product, Price)`, not `spread(dt, dt$Product, dt$Price)`. `spread` expects column names, not extracted columns.

Comment: Ok, yes that solves that, but now I get an error message that says "Each row of output must be identified by a unique combination of keys. Keys are shared for 21862 rows". What does this mean?

Comment: In your example, each ID has at most one Price for each Product. In your real data, that must not be the case. If ID 4 has two rows for Product A, one with Price = 5 and another with Price = 10, then `spread` doesn't know what value to put in the "A" column for ID 4---5, or 10.

Comment: Ok, thanks for explaining. Is there a way to use an aggregate function or how would I combat this?

Comment: `spread` doesn't have aggregation functions built-in, but if you go back to `reshape2::dcast` you can specify an aggregate. I think it would be `reshape2::dcast(dt, \`ID Number\` ~ Product, fun.aggregate = mean, value.var = "Price")`. Or you could aggregate with dplyr before spreading (modern approach) `dt %>% group_by(\`ID Number\`, Product) %>% summarize(Price = mean(Price)) %>% spread(Product, Price)`. Of course, switch out `mean` with any other aggregate function you want.